# DownloadManager fails with ERROR_UNKNOWN on API 17

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I'm trying to use android's own DownloadManager and it works perfectly on API 18+ but the same code fails (STATUS_FAILED) with reason ERROR_UNKNOWN almost as soon as I enqueue it on API 17 phones. here's my code

```
Context context = MyApplication.getSharedContext();
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE).setTitle(notiTitle).
setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+fileName);
request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(file));
DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
manager.enqueue(request) ;
```

Comment: I dont think it's related to your API version check net connection or something like this in your lower API devices. Download manager works fine on API 11 and above.

Comment: @Amir I tested this same code on several phones, both API 17 phones failed with ERROR_UNKNOWN and every API 18+ phones completed download without any issues. I've checked the connectivity and I'm sure there was no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After days of struggling with this problem , I accidentally discovered the root of the issue. the urls to downloads which were fetched from a server had "[" and "]" characters. they posed no problem in API 18+ DownloadManager but in API 17 the download fails with ERROR_UNKNOWN with no information as to why whatsoever.
replacing them with %5B and %5D respectively solved the problem.

```
url = url.replace("[","%5B").replace("]","%5D");
```